# If I make a program in 64 bit computer (let say from Intel) will it work on 64 bit IPhone

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, processor, opcode

If I make a program on 64 bit any machine with 64 bit processor from Intel will it run on 64 bit IPhone or any other device or computer from any company including any ARM_64 bit device if there are any.

Comment: Please ask one question per question.  If you write a program for amd64 (also known as x86_64 or Intel 64), it'll work on amd64 computers of the same operating system.  It's not going to work on arm64 devices such as an iPhone as arm64 is a different architecture.

Comment: As for mapping register names to numbers, refer to the *Intel Software Development Manuals*.  You should always have a copy of them open when writing assembly code.  Note that `b8`, `b9`, `ba`, and `bb` are not register numbers.  They are opcodes of the instruction `mov r32, imm32` with encoding `b8 +r`.

Comment: I have downvoted your question because it asks multiple things at once.  Please [edit] your question to only ask one thing.  Feel free to make multiple questions if you have multiple distinct questions.

Comment: @fuz can I edit and separate questions later. Should it be right now?

Comment: You should do so ideally before you post the question.  Now is a good time, too.

Answer (score 1):

No. Those are two different architectures. The executable is intended for a specific CPU architecture, and the fact that both are 64-bit platforms is far from being the main criteria.